# Cloning a GIT branch to another repositories GIT branch?

Tags: git, bash, github, migration, .git-info-grafts

I have two GIT repositories, one for work and one for independent development. My company expressed interest in a project I've been working on and would like me to migrate that branch (master) into a new branch on their repo (Features/Dynamo).  [I have created a migrator in the past](https://github.com/ehime/Bash-Tools/blob/master/GIT/git-mirror.sh) but this clobbers the repo being pushed to as it is a straight --bare then --mirror. What would I need to do in order to graft a branch from one repository to another (while creating the new branch in the process)?

Comment: Are there any shared files (same dir/filenames) ?

Comment: Can you just add the other repo as another remote and push your master from A to features/Dynamo on B?

Comment: And will this be a one-time transfer ?

Comment: This doesn't make sense? Why would you have two completely different projects in the same git repository as branches? Why not have two git repositories?

Comment: There are two git repositories, I would like to graft a branch from one repository to another, they want to use a wrapper that I wrote.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant yes this will be a one time transfer. Scowler, yes I could do that, I'm not positive how though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach is to add the other remote.

```
git remote add ehime https://github.com/your_username/your_repo_name.git
```

Now all the stuff you've done like

```
git push origin some_branch
```

can also be done as

```
git push ehime some_branch
```

for the other remote.

Thus two remotes but one directory of code.

In the case of shared files there are lots of options when doing a merge such as

```
git checkout branchA
git merge ours branchB
```

or

```
git checkout branchA
git merge -X theirs branchB
```

to control how merges are done between the two codebases.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to get a clone of the two repos on one machine, then in the "to" repo `git checkout -b new_branch` and then literally `cp` the files in from the other projects directory.  git add and git commit and you are done.  As I asked above, whether this would work would depend on if you have the same dir/filenames.  If you do you'd be presented with merge conflicts and the two different files would be smooshed together in a pretty bad way.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, this is what you could do, but I think you'd be better served having two different repositories. *NOTE: This will not bring over your entire git history, it will just add the most recent state of your project as a branch.*

```
$ git checkout -b OtherProject

-- to prevent losing your git database
$ mv .git/ /temp/gitBackup

-- clear out all the stuff from the main repository
$ rm -rf *

-- copy contents of the tip of master from your other project
-- but not the .git/ folder
$ cp -r /path/to/personal/project/* .
$ rm -rf .git/

-- bring back your old .git folder
$ mv /temp/gitBackup ./.git

-- add all your new files to this branch
$ git add -A .
$ git commit -am "The other project is now in this repo as a branch"
```

Again, this is not a recommended course of action. Your git database will grow much larger and this is not the intended use for branches. I would highly recommend using one repository per project and perhaps using [submodules](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) to manage sub projects from within your git repository.